# How to insert database jquery multi input?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I've a two jquery dynamic input. How can i insert database all items. Like this;

```
fatura  |   urun
  1         apple
  2         banana
```

Here the Html codes;

```
<form action="post.php" id="form" method="post">
    <input name="fatura[]" type="text" />
    <input name="urun[]" type="text" " />
  </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary input-ekle">Add Item</button>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

And here the post.php; (This codes only adding "fatura[]" input rows. I want to insert with urun input.)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO siparis (fatura_id) VALUES (:fi)";
$ekle = $db->prepare($sql);
$ekle->bindParam(':fi', $row);
foreach ($_POST['fatura'] as $row) {
$ekle->execute();
}
if ($ekle) {
echo "ok";
} else {
echo "bad";
}
```

Comment: What is the format of your database?

Comment: You have an extra double quote in `<input name="urun[]" type="text" " />`

Comment: Only id(AI), fatura_id and urun_ismi

Comment: It's was being added here. Not in the original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is as many "fatura" as "urun", you could try something like this :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO siparis (fatura_id, urun_ismi) VALUES (:fi, :ui)" ;
$ekle = $db->prepare($sql) ;
$num = count($_POST['fatura']) ;
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $num ; $i++) {
    $ekle->bindParam(':fi', $_POST['fatura'][$i]) ;
    $ekle->bindParam(':ui', $_POST['urun'][$i]) ;
    $ekle->execute();
}
```